# Update field in database, passing record ID through link

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a code doing the following. I want to retrieve records from MySQL database. Each record contains (Course name, From, To, Credit hours, Details). I then want to add link for each record. When the link for a record is clicked, I want to redirect to the another page to update the field state to 'Yes' for that record.

**Question**: how can I update a specific record in database depending on the ID of record? In other words, how can I make each link pass the ID of its record to the update page so I can update it without write a specific ID?

My table contains these fields :

```
ID ,
Course_name,
From ,
To ,
Credit_hours ,
Detailes ,
state
```

#### First page

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<title>Training Courses Registration System </title>

</head>
<body>
<table style="width:786px; position:relative;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;">
<tr>
  <td> 
<img src="4.png" class="header">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src="2.png" class="bar">
<a href="home-ar.html"style="font-size:17px;position:absolute;top:163px;right:16px;z-index:5;lang=ar; text-decoration:none;">عربي</a>

<a href=" "style="font-size:17px;position:absolute;top:165px;right:55px;z-index:5;   text-decoration:none;">Sign out |</a>
 <a href="logout.php"class="l" >Profile  &nbsp; </a> 
<a href=" "class="l1">Available Courses  &nbsp; </a>
<a href=" "class="l5">Approve Courses</a>
<a href=" "class="l4">Statistic</a>
   </td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
<section class="b"><section class="f1">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","m","11","wafa");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM internal");

?> 
<br>
<?php 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo ' <details> 
<summary style="padding-left:33px;">' . $row['Course_name'] . "
</summary>";
 echo "<P>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; From: &nbsp;".$row['From'] ."</p>" ;
 echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To: &nbsp;".$row['To'] . "</p>";
 echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Credit Hours: &nbsp;".$row['Credit_hours']."</p>" ;
 echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Detailes: &nbsp;". $row['Detailes'] ."</p>";
 echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a style='color:#387c25;background-color:#a6d898;' href='in3.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>Accept</a>
</p>
 </details> <br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>

 </section> 

</td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="footer">
<img src="3.png" class="footer"></div></section>

</td></tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

#### Second page

```
<?php 

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","m","11","wafa");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
 $topic =$_GET['ID']; 
}

 $sql = ("UPDATE internal set state = u WHERE ID = $topic");


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
header("Location: internal.html");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is very wrong:

```
$sql = ("UPDATE internal set state = u WHERE ID = $topic");
```

- You have an sql injection problem;
- You are using an undefined column / element `u`.

It should be something like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE internal set state = 'Yes' WHERE ID = ?";
```

And then you bind your variable to the placeholder (the question mark), using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

**Note:**

- You should also have checks to see if the referenced record can be changed by the user, otherwise a user could edit arbitrary records by changing the url (or the post data, see the next point);
- You should use `POST` instead of `GET` if you are going to modify information in the database.
- You should add error handling to your database calls. The easiest way to do that in mysqli is to have it throw exceptions. To enable that, just put this at the top of your script: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: I noticed OP's using two potentially used reserved words `to` and `from`, however is not showing up in the question. Wondering if that could be a contributing factor (big question mark). *"my table contains these fields : ID , Course_name, `From` , `To` , Credit_hours"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I noticed that too, but the OP would have to specify the exact problem to see if that is the case. Judging by the code posted it is not...

Comment: Judging by posted code, not (as you said). Yet, you know how some new posters tend to leave out the juicy stuff sometimes. ;)

Comment: Yet, after reading the question again *"i want to retrieve records each record contains (Course name , `from` , `to` , credit hours , details)"* - this tells me that it's unclear as to what OP is asking.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm guessing this question qualifies as a `can of worms` in your book ;-)

Comment: Indeed it does, a very big, deep and dark one at that ;) (not deep "fried" though) yuck. I'll leave those for the fish & birds.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my question is how can I update a specific record in database depend on the ID of record, in other word how can I make each link pass the ID of its record to the update page so I can update it without write a specific ID ?